# How Can I add an item to an array using eval feature in RavenDB?

Tags: c#, push, eval, ravendb, patch

Considering the following database document:

[image]

I need push an element to array highlighted field "Roles".

I've tried the code below but without success. I need to know which command use in place of "SelectWhere"...

```
patches.Add(new ScriptedPatchCommandData
                {
                    Key = "Users/" + (mp.EnableChangeUserName ? user.ProviderUserKey : username),
                    Patch = new ScriptedPatchRequest
                    {
                        Script = @"
                                var app = this.Applications.SelectWhere(function(application){ 
                                    return application.Key == appKey;
                                });
                                if(app != null) { app.Roles.PushAll(roles) }",
                        Values = { { "appKey", mp.ApplicationKey }, {"roles", roleNames} }
                    }
                });
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.Applications.length; i++)
{
  var app = this.Applications[i];
  if (app.Key == appKey)
  {
    app.Roles = app.Roles.concat(roles);
  }
}
```

When testing in the Raven Management Studio, It seems that you can't represent an array in the Parameters window, so I had to enter it as a string `["foo","bar"]` and make one minor change to the script:

```
...   .concat(eval(roles))
```